# How to moq a IEnumerable<T> to pass Any() condition check

Tags: c#, moq

I'm encountering some problems to use `Moq` framework with `IEnumerable`. I have no problem with mocking an object, but there is something I don't get about mocking `IEnumerable`, `ICollection` of an object and so on.

For example:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void UnitTest()
{
    var mockedExample = new Mock<IEnumerable<Class>>();

    var feedback = repository.SomeMethod(mockedExample.Object);
}

public void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<Class> input)
{
    if (input != null && input.Any())
    {
       //Stuff to do
    }
}
```

My problem is when I check input. I pass the `input != null` condition but I get an error on the `input.Any()` condition.

How can I setup the mocked IEnumerable to pass both the conditions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to? Just pass in a know value and judge if you get the correct output and/or that the correct dependencies are ran correctly.

Comment: just pass in a `List<Class>` that you initialize with objects for the test.  Typically you mock class dependencies, then build concrete objects to send as parameters to your tested method.

Comment: There is never (well, *almost* never) a need to mock `IEnumerable`; even if you needed to set up a completely custom iteration which the standard collections couldn't provide (like an infinite or dynamic enumeration), that's what iterator methods are for.

Comment: You are using wrong tool, mocks are used to mock dependencies which slows down the tests or dependencies which belongs to totally different domain. In all other cases don't mock, but use actual objects - in your case this is `Enumerable.Empty<Class>` or `new[] { new Class() }`

Comment: Thank you everyone. I followed your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by people I don't think you need a mock here. I think the right option is provided in the comments.

But to answer your question: You should specify the behavior of the Any method (using the "setup" method on the mock) :

```
mockedExample.Setup(m => m.Any()).Returns(true);
```

But if you triy to do that you will have this exception :

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: m =>
> m.Any() Extension methods (here: Enumerable.Any) may not be
> used in setup / verification expressions.'

That's because, "Any" is not part of the IEnumerable interface (even if the usage tends to make you believe it is). "Any" is an extension method (so basically a simple static method) of IEnumerable.

```
public static bool Any<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source)
```

[Source is here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__)

It basically means you cannot mock the behavior of the "Any" method directly using Moq.

But if you check what is inside the "Any" method:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        return e.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

When the GetEnumerator of your mock object is called the default value is returned (since you do not setup any behavior for it) which is "null" so the "e.MoveNext()" call is failing. So you can define the "GetEnumerator" behavior and make it works but I really think the solution provided in the comments are way easier and will make a more readable code.